# Symfony2 querybuilder join not working in Sonata bundle for join

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to create a simple form with sonata bundle. I have one problem trying to load data entity type field. I know this is working:

```
$formMapper->add( 'foo', 'entity', array(
    'class'         => 'myVendorMyBundleBundle:Foo',
    'property'      => 'id',
    'query_builder' => function(FooRepository $er) {
        return $er->createQueryBuilder('qb')
        ->add( 'select', 'f' )
        ->add( 'from', 'myVendorMyBundleBundle:Foo f' )
    },
'label'         => 'foo'
) );
```

The problem is I don't want to show entity id, I want to show its name, which is in a related table. I tried to use join statement at createQueryBuilder method, but I didn't get it to work:

```
$formMapper->add( 'foo', 'entity', array(
    'class'         => 'myVendorMyBundleBundle:Foo',
    'property'      => 'b.name',
    'query_builder' => function(FooRepository $er) {
        return $er->createQueryBuilder('qb')
        ->add( 'select', 'f' )
        ->add( 'from', 'myVendorMyBundleBundle:Foo f' )
        ->add( 'join', 'myVendorMyBundleBundle:Bar b' )
    },
'label'         => 'foo'
) );
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Please add the error you receive.

Comment: i don't understand why use something like this instead to make a plain old faster sql string on your own

Comment: I got this error trying to get name property:

Neither property "nom" nor method "getName()" nor method "isName()" exists in class "MyBundle\Entity\Foo

Name is a bar entity property. It seems I can only get info from foo entity...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make a `__toString()` method on the entity you are using, Symfony will automatically use that as the label.

Edit:
In your `myVendorMyBundleBundle:Foo` class you should have a variable `$bar` defined

```
<?php

// ../app/src/myVendor/MyBundleBundle/Entity/Foo.php

public function __toString()
{
    // If relationship is many to one or one to one
    return $this->bar->getSomeProperty();

    //If relationship is one to many or many to many
    $return_var = '';
    foreach($this->bars as $bar)
    {
        $return_var .= $bar->getSomeProperty() . ' ';
    }

    return $return_var
}
```

Doctrine will lazy load in the association (not an issue if you are working with a low/singular number of labels)...I have used this method effectively to do what you are describing

```
<?php
$b->add('foo', 'entity', array(
     'class' => 'myVendorMyBundleBundle:Foo',
));
```

Comment: Hi Pete, thanks but it will just work for the foo Entity, and I want to select data from the bar entity.

Comment: If you have properly defined your relationship in your mapping. Your `__toString()` method could look something shown in my edit